# Evitar acesso simultâneo do usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, token, token-ajax

Preciso fazer com que o usuário não faça login no sistema (`asp-net` `mvc`) em maquinas diferentes.
O sistema está na intranet e atualmente existe uma tabela de Acesso com data e hora de acesso do usuário e com outra coluna Logado (S/N).
Como posso fazer esse controle ?

Acredito que gerar um token como o [Antonio Campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4101/ant%C3%B3nio-campos) disse seria a melhor maneira, poré fiz algumas pesquisa no google como [gerar token com asp net mvc](https://www.google.com.br/search?num=30&newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=X6bLW_W6GMa85gKt_5OQDA&btnG=Pesquisar&q=gerar%20token%20com%20asp%20net%20mvc&oq=radio%20fm%20bl&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l4j0i22i30k1l6.6889.13323.0.16057.13.12.0.0.0.0.547.2033.0j2j5j5-1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.9.2375.6..35i39k1j0i131k1.345.Na7BnyTH4GE) porém fiquei um pouco confuso pois as explicações que encontrei sempre são associados a gerar token para se autenticar a uma Web API e o sistema no qual trabalho não acessa uma Web API: acessa banco de dados.

Comment: você não pode por exemplo apagar a data/hora que ele acessou quando efetuar o logof? dessa forma se tentar logar e já tiver um valor nesse campo vai saber que ele já está logado

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual esqueci de mencionar que o usuário pode feche o browser sem clicar no botão logof então não tenho como apagar a data conforme você disse.

Comment: mas isso pode acontecer com qualquer site, não é algo se vc tenha controle, nem com eventos. você pode tratar isso com um controle de atividade, se o usuário ficar muito tempo sem interagir com o backend pode matar a sessão dele, é o que os bancos fazem

Comment: Trabalhei em um banco onde tinha aplicações web na intranet em que o usuário só conseguia se logar no sistema em uma máquina por vez e não simultânea, mas não sei qual era o procedimento.

Comment: @adianojc, depende também de como você quer fazer esse controle... quando já estiver logado deve bloquear um novo login em outra máquina? (mais fácil) Ou vai deslogar a sessão antiga? (Mais difícil de controlar)

Comment: @Leandro Angelo isso ! Bloquear um novo login em outra maquina

Comment: Adicione o código do seu login

Comment: Adicionar um token que geras no login que validas em cada pedido, se na validação o token for diferente do da base de dados quer dizer que fez login em outro sitio e invalidas ou fazes logout na sessão que tem o token inválido.

Comment: Você pode fazer verificação por ip, ou então fazer um session token, como dito acima.

Comment: @Antonio Campos eu editei o post para ficar mais claro minha dúvida e como você pode ver achei interessante a geração do token porém como dito as explicações que encontro é direcionado para Web API e o sistema que trabalho não acessa WebAPI e sim diretamente um Banco de Dados Oracle.

Comment: @hard123 Quando sugeri usar um Token estava a sugerir o seguinte:
1 - Criar um campo Token na tabela onde autenticas o utilizador
2- Quando autenticas o utilizador alteras esse Token para um novo Guid()
3- Guardas esse Guid num cookie (por exemplo)
4- Quando validas cada pedido verificas se o Token que veio do Cookie é igual ao da tabela, se for aceitas o pedido, se não for é porque o utilizador fez login em outro sitio por isso não tem login feito atualmente e solicitas que faça login (ou o procedimento que tens para logout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saber se o usuário está logado e inibir um segundo login dependem muito de como é o comportamento do usuário na sua aplicação.

Se seu sistema usa sessão, com o identificador de sessão do usuário você pode inibir o início de uma segunda sessão, mas vale lembrar que, se você não tem um processo contínuo para validar essa sessão, o usuário já pode ter deixado a página e a sessão será considerada até a expiração.

Você pode adotar uma sessão curta com processo de renovação (vale lembrar que o custo dessa operação deve ser analisada).

Se seu problema é manter somente uma sessão aberta, você pode trabalhar para manter o acesso somente para última sessão, via identificador da sessão, registra a nova e retira acesso da anterior.

Se for via token, você pode revogar a validade do primeiro token e manter o segundo.

Dependendo do foco do seu produto, também pode utilizar sockets para realmente entender quando o usuário está realmente ativo e ainda ter uma comunicação direta em tempo real. Lembrando que o custo deve ser analisado.